# How to automation application that does not have login page instead uses EIDP auth token to login and have application access?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, automation, selenium-chromedriver

My application works on login via auth token for ex: when I launch the application it logs me into the application as per my user permissions.
**Application uses EIDP token.**
How would I automate that using python selenium?